# Location Change listener continuing to broadcast events after being removed

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-maps

Ive implemented this interface

```
class LocationListener(eventManager: RoadSnappedLocationProviderEventManager): RoadSnappedLocationProvider.LocationListener {
    var eventMananagerRef: RoadSnappedLocationProviderEventManager? = null
    init{
        eventMananagerRef = eventManager;
    }
    override fun onLocationChanged(p0: Location?) {
        Log.d("TZ", ("TZZZ  $p0.toString()"))
        val params: WritableMap = Arguments.createMap()
        params.putString("message", p0.toString())
        eventMananagerRef?.sendEvent(LOCATION_UPDATE_RECEIVED, params)
    }

    override fun onRawLocationUpdate(p0: Location?) {
        val params: WritableMap = Arguments.createMap()
        eventMananagerRef?.sendEvent(LOCATION_UPDATE_RECEIVED, params)
    }
}
```

And I am attaching it to NavigationApi.getRoadSnappedLocationProvider like so:

```
override fun onNavigatorReady(navigator: Navigator) {
                mNavigator = navigator
                locationListenerRef = LocationListener(eventManager)
                Log.d("TZ starting snapped ", locationListenerRef.toString())
                NavigationApi.getRoadSnappedLocationProvider(reactContext?.currentActivity?.application ?: Application()).addLocationListener(locationListenerRef)
            }
```

It starts to fire location change events and when I call the method to remove it:

```
fun removeLocationListenerProvider(promise: Promise) {
        try {
            Log.d("TZ", ("REMOVING LOCATION LISTENER + ${locationListenerRef.toString()}"))
            NavigationApi.getRoadSnappedLocationProvider(reactContext?.currentActivity?.application ?: Application()).removeLocationListener(locationListenerRef)
            locationListenerRef = null
            Log.d("TZ", "REMOVED LOCATION LISTENER")
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            Log.d("TZ", e.toString())
        }
    }
```

I continue seeing the event handlers firing. Doc for road snapped location provider: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/navigation/android-sdk/v2/reference/com/google/android/libraries/navigation/RoadSnappedLocationProvider#removeLocationListener(com.google.android.libraries.navigation.RoadSnappedLocationProvider.LocationListener)

Comment: presumably this is Java / Android - please edit the associated tags to correlate

Comment: I would start by removing `?: Application()` in both occurrences. You cannot just create an instance of `Application` and expect it to work. If for some reason `reactContext?.currentActivity?.application` evaluates to `null`, log something and skip the work. After that, confirm that `NavigationApi.getRoadSnappedLocationProvider()` returns the same instance in both the add and remove paths, and confirm that you have the same `locationListenerRef` instance in both the add and remove paths.

Comment: @CommonsWare yep.. the second part of your answer was the culprit. cheers